# error getting currentuser child , firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, getter

here is my code

```
myRef.child("Donors").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
                    String s=user.getUserName();
...
```

I get the following error : 
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.sy.food.UserInformation.getUserName()' on a null object reference.
How can I make it work ?

[EDIT]
here is my database https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqDYP.png

[SOLVED ]
myRef was referencing another child of my database not directly to database and I did not pay attention to that. that's what caused the nullPointerException.

Comment: there is no users node in your database

Comment: actually the children under Donors are users' IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are skipping one child so Firebase can not retrieve data like:

```
        myRef.child("food-d152b").child("Users").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User user = snapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
            String s=user.getUserName();
```

Comment: I want to getValue only for the current user, in fact I applied addValueEventListener to myRef.child("Donors").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()) not to myRef.child("Donors").

Comment: Than you are missing one child probably. Do you accessing first child `food-d152b`? Or `getUid()` is not correct? Or there is a miss match in POJO class and child names?

Comment: You're right, I checked myRef and it was referencing another child of my database , I was thinking it was referencing the database, and that is why I have the nullPointerException. However, as @PeterHaddad  mentioned, I needed change getUserName to getName so that the solution works

Comment: Actually you don't have to change you can use annotation `@PropertyName("Name")` but you have to either your variable declaration make `public` like `public String username` or use annotation `@PropertyName("Name")` above your  `getters` and `setters`